# Jenkins Workspace Directory has @# on the end?

Tags: jenkins

I have a job that just started to add @# to the end of its workspace. Now idea why. Nothing changed in the job, the job is not marked to run concurrently.

Clearing the workspace doesn't reset it to normal. How do I make Jenkins do what is has always done and use the job name as the workspace without the @# on the end?

Comment: The "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" check box is disabled? If yes, try to restart the jenkins. This solved the issue once for me.

Comment: @S.Spieker - Restarting Jenkins did it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` check box is disabled?

If yes, try to restart the jenkins. This solved the issue once for me.